# Laravel 5.7 Override vendor class and extend old one

Tags: php, laravel, alias

So the solution was to create a new ServiceProvider.

This solution works for Override

```
php artisan make:provider MyServiceProvider
```

Which extended the Vendor service provider (found within config/app.php). Within that ServiceProvider, add my alias within the overridden *register* method

```
 $loader->alias('Vendor\VendorName\Class', 'App\Vendor\MyCustomClass');
```

### https://stackoverflow.com/a/47926486/10589868

Now, how do I extend the overridden class? I tried this:

```
$loader->alias('ClassParent', 'Vendor\VendorName\Class');
$loader->alias('Vendor\VendorName\Class', 'App\Vendor\MyCustomClass');
...
class MyCustomClass extends ClassParent {} // not working
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to do is extend the Vendor class:

```
class MyCustomClass extends Vendor\VendorName\Class {}
```

Now, this class has the properties and methods of the Vendor class and the properties and methods you've added.

Then, your custom class can become an alias:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        // add the lines bellow
        $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('App\Vendor\MyCustomClass', 'Vendor\VendorName\Class');
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, maybe i wasn't clear enough... Now it's only extends older class. I want to override it, not to use it directly. This class is been used in other vendor class, and i want to use my overridden and extended class.
exp.
VendorClass1 {}
VendorClass2 {
  using VendorClass1;
}
MyClass extend VendorClass1 {}

----
MyClass is alias for VendorClass1
VendorClass2 is using MyClass, not VendorClass1

Comment: @JanGrb Oh, I see. I think this will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435747/laravel-extend-a-vendor-class-installed-from-composer.

This also gives some outside hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884764/laravel-extend-form-class

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. Where does `$loader->alias` go?

Comment: @brandonbanks I think it goes in `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` class, inside the `register` method -- I just updated the answer