# Laravel Spark extend Laravel\Cashier vendor class to override function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier, laravel-spark

I'm looking to override Cashier's `SubscriptionBuilder::buildPayload()`. Which looks like:

```
    protected function buildPayload()
    {
        return array_filter([
            'billing_cycle_anchor' => $this->billingCycleAnchor,
            'coupon' => $this->coupon,
            'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
            'metadata' => $this->metadata,
            'plan' => $this->plan,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'tax_percent' => $this->getTaxPercentageForPayload(),
            'trial_end' => $this->getTrialEndForPayload(),
            'off_session' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

I'm looking to add 1 param to this which is `'collection_method': 'invoice'`

So I'm trying to override this function so I can modify it.

I tried a few things, namely following some of the below answers:

[Strategy to override a class in a library installed with Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104574/strategy-to-override-a-class-in-a-library-installed-with-composer/34600074)

[Laravel 5.7 Override vendor class and extend old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097256/laravel-5-7-override-vendor-class-and-extend-old-one)

I have added my `CustomSubscriptionBuilder` in `App\SparkOverrides\`

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Cashier;

class CustomSubscriptionBuilder extends SubscriptionBuilder
{
    protected function buildPayload()
    {
        dd('here');
    }
}
```

Then in `composer.json` I have added:

```
"autoload": {
        ...
        "files": [
            "app/SparkOverrides/CustomSubscriptionBuilder.php"
        ]
    },
```

I have then run `composer dump-autoload`. But then when I try and create a subscription the `dd()` never gets hit. To make matters more confusing, I have added a dump and die to the `vendor` `buildPayload()` and that isn't getting hit either.

I feel like I'm close but am missing something. Thanks for any help.

Comment: just because you made a class that extends another class doesn't mean that anything knows your new class exists ... where this SubscriptionBuilder is needed it is hard coded into the `Billable` trait `@newSubscription`

Comment: That makes sense but it doesn't get me any closer to figuring out how to solve this problem.

Comment: well its hardcocded in a trait, so extend the trait and override the method and use your new extended trait in your model or in the model override the method

Comment: Thanks for the tips @lagbox! I was able to get it.

Comment: nice, glad you got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Thank you to @lagbox for pointing me in the right direction.

I created a `CustomBillable` class and a `CustomSubscriptionBuilder` class.

Both of these classes are in `app/SparkOverrides/`

```php
<?php

namespace App\SparkOverrides;

use Laravel\Spark\Billable;

trait CustomBillable
{
    use Billable;

    /**
     * Overriding Cashier's newSubscription to use
     * my CustomSubscriptionBuilder
     */
    public function newSubscription($subscription, $plan)
    {
        return new CustomSubscriptionBuilder($this, $subscription, $plan);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\SparkOverrides;

use Laravel\Cashier\SubscriptionBuilder;

class CustomSubscriptionBuilder extends SubscriptionBuilder
{
    protected function buildPayload()
    {
        return array_filter([
            'billing_cycle_anchor' => $this->billingCycleAnchor,
            'coupon' => $this->coupon,
            'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
            'metadata' => $this->metadata,
            'plan' => $this->plan,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'tax_percent' => $this->getTaxPercentageForPayload(),
            'trial_end' => $this->getTrialEndForPayload(),
            'off_session' => true,
            'collection_method' => 'send_invoice',
            'days_until_due' => 30,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then I replaced the `Billable` trait with my `CustomBillable` trait on the `Spark\User`.

```php
<?php

namespace Laravel\Spark;

use App\SparkOverrides\CustomBillable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use CustomBillable, HasApiTokens, RoutesNotifications;
    ...
}
```

The App's `User` extends `Spark\User`. So now when `newSubscription()` is called it uses `CustomBillable`'s `newSubscription()` which in turn uses the `CustomSubscriptionBuilder`.

I hope this helps someone out. Been tinkering for a while on this one.

Comment: The right way to do this is to write a class that implements `Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Interactions\Subscribe` interface and inject it in the container via the `register` method of `SparkServiceProvider` class. Take a look at `Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider::registerServices()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but you could just override the `newSubscription` method in the `App\User` class which inherits it from the `Laravel\Spark\User` class. Just a thought...